# IE11 and IE10 CSS Problems in Magento2

Tags: magento2, css

We currently have the problem that Magento2 renders wrong in IE11 and IE10.

This Screenshot has been made with IE11 settings in Safari. On our Windows Machine it renders the same (as well IE11).

[image]

The free space has the following structure and styling:

```
<body class="ie11">
...

<div class="page-wrapper">
     <div class="another-class nav"></div>
     <div class="another-class subnav"></div>
     <div class="another-class menu"></div>

     <main id="maincontent" class="page-main">
     <!-- several DIVs, no content --> 
     </main>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.ie11 .page-wrapper #maincontent {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The elements in between main are set to `display:none;`

What can I do to hide this element completly? The slider should be on the edge of the end of the menu.

Second problem: 
On the product pages the footer comes to the viewport bottom: 0px.

Example:
[image]

The CSS for this element is:

```
.ie11 .page-footer, .ie10 .page-footer  {display: inline-block; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; clear:both;}
```

Please advise how to solve this problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1)

> The elements in between main are set to display:none;
>
> What can I do to hide this element completly? The slider should be on the edge of the end of the menu.

My assumption is this is a custom landing page with a slider? You made a page in the backend with a cms block linking to it?  To fully remove this area you will need to use XMl in your template.  Possibly in your layout XML file of your theme.

Moving on with how to do this using css to make it display properly you are using `display: none;`

I would also try with IE

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

Answer 2)
Your code from main content A) worries me a little and B) also is right above your footer?

```
.ie11 .page-wrapper #maincontent {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Is this a sticky footer?  My assumption is no.

In the code you have both `max-height` and `min-height` set to 100px;  Why do this if height is already set to 100px?  These are used to be more flexible in my opinion not just to set them the same as the height.  Now if height was a percentage % I could understand setting one or both of these.

You need to use chrome developer tools or something similar in IE to look into this.  Try some code like this.  My thoughts are the reason your content block is looking shorter is `overflow: hidden` is supposed to expand your element to wrap elements within.  It cannot do this because `height`, `min-height` and `max-height` are all set.  Remove `height` and `max-height` so it is not limited.

```
.ie11 .page-wrapper #maincontent {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Why not add a height property onto your footer as well?   Also, clear: both is on your footer, but not on the parent element and I assume to get around this you added `display: inline-block;` on the footer so you wouldn't need to clear floats on the parent element.

Comment: Actually it worked when I removed overflow:hidden attribute... However, your solutions seems to be correct as well - even more correct, just without the overflow: hidden.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help you.